# VBA use string as variable name

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have workbooks with datasets (of varying lengths) from measurements in different rooms.  I need to sort each datasets.
My code finds the start and end rows of each dataset and stores them as StartRowRoom1, EndRowRoom1, StartRowRoom2, EndRowRoom2 etc.

I want to go through each dataset in a while loop like this.

```
Dim StartRowRoom1 As Integer
Dim StartRowRoom2 As Integer
Dim EndRowRoom1 As Integer
Dim EndRowRoom2 As Integer

n = 1

While n < NumberOfRooms
    startRow = "StartRowRoom" & n
    endRow = "EndRowRoom" & n

    With Range(Cells(startRow, 4), Cells(endRow, 4))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]+RC[-1]"
        #sorting and graph creation
    End With
    n = n + 1
Wend
```

My problem is that the startRow and endRow variables are strings ("StartRowRoom1" and "EndRowRoom1", for n=1). so they cannot be used in  Cells(). I want them to refer to the variables defined as integers.
Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what arrays are for.

You should declare your variables as

```
Dim StartRowRoom(1 to 2) As Integer
Dim EndRowRoom(1 to 2) As Integer

StartRowRoom(1) = [your value here]
StartRowRoom(2) = [your value here]

EndRowRoom(1) = [your value here]
EndRowRoom(2) = [your value here]
```

Then you can access them as

```
startRow = StartRowRoom(n)
endRow = EndRowRoom(n)
```

using `n` as the index

Comment: Arrays, Collections or Dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to store the StartRowRoom1 variables like Range type and use .offset()  and .end() in getting that references.

Then in your loop you don't need the Cells(,):

```
With Range(startRow, endRow) ...
```